# Find three implicit functions from the given equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was trying to solve question 36 from section 2.7 (implicit functions) of Zill and Dewar's precalc with calc previews.

The question is as follows:
Give three piecewise-defined functions f, g, and h, with domain [−3, 3], defined implicitly by the equation

$$ 
x^2 + y^2 = 9
$$

I can get 2 implicit funcs as follows

$$
\\y^2 = 9-x^2
\\y = \pm \sqrt{9-x^2}
$$

What is the third implicit function? Is there a mistake in the question?